# How can i convert from string to emoji in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Hello i want to convert the emoji from string in typescript to show emoji in html.

> Typescript file

```
export class Example {
    emoji:any;
    function(){
       this.emoji = ":joy:"
    }
  }
```

in **HTML** file i want it to be like 
  
(this is the element emoji which i will get from the typescript file)
Is something like this possible and how.
All help is appreciated

Comment: yes but it will be dynamic website so i wont put the emojis like the one i put here. I have them strings on the backend and i need to display them as i mentioned in the front-end. I dont know if is it possible @DanielBeck

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you need some sort of mapping of :joy: to relevant unicode string.

For example: The unicode code for :joy: would be `&#x1f602`.

You can then use this to print on the page...

Here's a little example.

```js
var mapping = {

":joy:" : "&#x1f602",
  ":shades:": "&#x1f60e",
  ":happy:" : "&#x1f600"

}

var iteration = 0;

function mapEmoji(){

  
setInterval(function(){
   if(iteration == Object.keys(mapping).length)
 iteration = 0;
  
   var text = Object.keys(mapping)[iteration];
   document.getElementById("emoji").innerHTML = mapping[text];
 iteration++;
  }, 500);
}

mapEmoji();
```

```html
<div id="emoji">

</div>
```

Of course you'll want to add more emojis to your unicode mapping object and you probably will want something to replace the placeholders (":joy:") with corresponding unicode code to replace within a sentence etc...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that with an `emoji map` and a `regular expression` would replace them in text:

```js
const emojiMap = {
  joy: "&#x1f602",
  shades: "&#x1f60e",
  happy: "&#x1f600"
}
const regExpression = /:([^:]*):/g
const text = "I was like :joy: and she was like :happy: and we ware like :shades:"

const emojiIt = (re, text) => {
  while (result = re.exec(text)) {
    text = text.replace(result[0], emojiMap[result[1]])
  }
  return text
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = emojiIt(regExpression, text)
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Since we are matching between the `:` we get the matched words form the regEx and then we use those (without the `:` since we tap into the group with index [1]) to get the appropriate html value.

PS. Thanks to **Adriani6** for the convenient html representation of the emojis!